# Entity framework performance when using methods in the select clause

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, code-first

I'm looking at the SQL generated when performing simple select queries. I'm using code first with the sample blog context from nuget.

If the following is run:

```
BlogContext _context = new BlogContext();
var comments = _context.Comments.Select(c => new CommentReadOnly {Author = c.Author});
var count = comments.Count();
```

The following SQL is produced:

```
SELECT 
  [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[Comments] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Where the count is performed in the SQL which is expected.

However if I change the code to look like this:

```
BlogContext _context = new BlogContext();
var comments = _context.Comments.Select(c => new CommentReadOnly {Author = c.Author});
var count = comments.Count();

private CommentReadOnly ToCommentReadOnly(Comment comment)
{
  return new CommentReadOnly
  {
    Author = comment.Author,
  };
}
```

The following SQL is produced:

```
SELECT 
 [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
 [Extent1].[PostID] AS [PostID], 
 [Extent1].[Text] AS [Text], 
 [Extent1].[Author] AS [Author]
FROM [dbo].[Comments] AS [Extent1]
```

With the `count` done in code.

The reason (I think) is because the first is returned as `IQueryable` where as the second is `IEnumerable`.

Is it possible to return the second query as IQueryable without executing the SQL?

The reason I ask is that I'm creating a generic repository layer that can query my entities and convert them to the required type (in the example above comment might have a couple of different 'readonly' objects). I don't want the SQL executing so early as paging may be done or other filtering in different situations.

Comment: Aren't the two code snippets exactly the same? The query is excuted with `.Count()` and I see no difference in the code before `.Count()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any difference in those two queries. However, I guess you want to return a IQueryable object to the client so the client can perform further filtering and get the count from there.

You can simply return the object without doing the select and let the client do the rest.

```
return _context.Comments
```

The client can perform additional filtering on this IQueryable object

Answer (score 0):

I think in your second query you execute the function ToCommentReadOnly() so this can't be done entirely in SQL and you end up with a Linq To Objects (IEnumerable).

But you state that you want to return an IQueryable from your Repository. This is not a recommended practice! The code to access the data should be hidden inside your repository otherwhise you will run into problems.

Say for example that your repository (which encapsulates your ObjectContext) goes out of scope after which you try to enumerate the IQueryable result the repository gave you. This will throw an error because the IQueryable can't be executed anymore.

If you expose an IQueryable from your Repository you give the end user of your Repository all the freedom they want in building their own queries, which is the thing you want to avoid by adding a repository!

So returning an IEnumerable from your Repository is a good thing :)

Comment: I would not agree that exposing `IQueryable` and a context reference outside of the respository is *generally* "not a recommended practice". There are as many reason in favor to do so (simplicity, direct projection into ViewModels, handling large data and data virtualization in desktop apps, lazy loading, etc.) as against this practice.

Comment: Well one example is when you are trying to optimize your queries. In our repositories we use CompiledQueries for performance. If we would expose IQueryable instead of IEnumerable, the compiling would be useless if the users of the repository would alter the queries and use the precompiling. And by using IQueryable you also couples your your code to the Entity Framework. The whole idea of the Repository pattern is to be independent of your persistent mechanism. We expose POCO's or custom DTO's from our data layer which suit the needs of the upper layers.

Comment: I know :) These are the good points and the theory always sounds good. But rarely the *costs* in practice (in time and development effort) are mentioned when it comes to "Independency of persistence mechanism" and encapsulation of data access. Don't misunderstand me, I don't say that your points are never correct, but I disagree that the points are *always* correct.